# How to bring a sub menu or a command under the context menu (Package Explorer) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am able to bring commands under

**1) File > New >**

[image]

Also under **File**

[image]

**Inside Context Menu (Package Explorer)** - When you right-click on a particular project in Package Explorer.

[image]

However, I had no luck bringing the same commands INSIDE the sub-menu(**New**) of the context menu.

I tried adding

```
  <menuContribution allPopups="true" locationURI="popup:common.new.menu?after=new">
     <command commandId="org.meri.eclipse.defensiveapitools.generatetostring" label="Generate Custom toString" style="push"></command>
     <command commandId="org.meri.eclipse.defensiveapitools.checknonnullparameter" label="Check Non-Null Parameter" style="push"></command>
  </menuContribution>
```

but it doesn't reflect in

[image]

Here is my plugin.xml file -

```
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution allPopups="true" locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">
         <command commandId="org.meri.eclipse.defensiveapitools.generatetostring" label="Generate Custom toString" style="push"></command>
         <command commandId="org.meri.eclipse.defensiveapitools.checknonnullparameter" label="Check Non-Null Parameter" style="push"></command>
      </menuContribution>

      <menuContribution allPopups="true" locationURI="menu:file?after=additions">
         <command commandId="org.meri.eclipse.defensiveapitools.generatetostring" label="Generate Custom toString" style="push"></command>
         <command commandId="org.meri.eclipse.defensiveapitools.checknonnullparameter" label="Check Non-Null Parameter" style="push"></command>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution allPopups="true" locationURI="menu:new?after=additions">
         <command commandId="org.meri.eclipse.defensiveapitools.generatetostring" label="Generate Custom toString" style="push"></command>
         <command commandId="org.meri.eclipse.defensiveapitools.checknonnullparameter" label="Check Non-Null Parameter" style="push"></command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Check this links. https://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t107410.html

Comment: @Sambit : The thread seems to be quite old.

Comment: The new menu is special, you use a new wizard to add to that. Use the new wizard shortcut in the perspectives extensions extension point to define a top level of the new menu.

Comment: @greg-449 : My solution above works for Project Explorer but not for Package Explorer. Does the locationURI="popup:common.new.menu?after=new" is also dependent on the VIEW?

Comment: Adding to the New menu using anything other than new wizards is not really supported. It may work in some views but won't hook in to the New wizard manager properly.

Comment: @greg-449: where can i find the latest changes done to the plugin dev? Can u please guide?

Comment: None of the APIs for Eclipse 3.x compatibilty mode have changed significantly in years. Old articles are mostly still valid as is the Eclipse help. Read about the org.eclipse.ui.newWizards and org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions extension points

Comment: @greg-449: Thanks. My confusion originated with [Adding to the New menu using anything other than new wizards is not really supported]. So those locationURI things and like are still used or have they been deprecated. Does changes to Main Menu, Toolbar, Context and Source Menu happens through LocationURI still. If not, can u help me to refer to a proper detailed chapter on how to create a proper functioning plugin?

Comment: menuContribution with locationURI is fine for other menus, it is just the New menu (also Import and Export) that is handled specially

Comment: @greg-449: so any changes done to sub-menus(Inside New) whether it comes under Context Menu, Source Menu or Main Menu must be done through Wizards?

Comment: Yes, just one new wizard covers all those places.